# C++ / Linux - File location address on hard drive

Tags: c++, file, virtual-machine, snap

I need to create some files on a ubuntu core (22.04) VM within a SNAP Environment.

- first file: contains some metadata and the absolute addresses of min. two other files on the same hard-drive.
- second & third file: contains custom data sets which used to identify the files.

With these 3 files, i want to check if the VM got cloned on the same hard-drive. If the two absolute addresses changed, but the distance between the to file addresses remain the same, there is a chance, that the VM got cloned. So the addresses on the hard-drive is the only variable i can use.

How do i get the absolute addresses from the files? I know, it is dependent on the format (ext4, fat32,...) and it is against the encapsulation of the OS. I checked the `File* struct`
but due to the usage of kernel methods and drivers, i can't get the information i need.

Maybe someone have an idea how to solve this or which objects/methods i can use instead of files?

I found some interesting things like the possibility to open the hard-drive as a file or to iterate through the blocks. But it is not possible for this environment.

Comment: Bad news: "if the VM got cloned", then as far as the VM appears, ***everything*** about it appears to be identical to the cloned-from system. This is exactly what a VM is for: to prevent the virtualized environment from knowing ***anything*** about ***anything*** outside of its virtualized environment. VMs don't work any other way. What you are really thinking about is containers, but VMs more than just containers. Inside the VM, "open the hard-drive as a file" will open the virtualized hard drive. Which will be identical to the cloned-from virtualized hard drive.

Comment: This has the smell of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to check if the VM was cloned? What underlying and actual problem would that knowledge solve?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, that is the reason why i need a way to get the *real* addresses. The VM is going to save this parameter because it is the only way to check if it is still the "real one".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need it as security mechanism. The underlaying problem is to protect a floating licence server (VM) against the cloning.

Comment: Maybe restrict who can clone your VMs. Your VM Manager should already provide tools like authentication and fine-grained permission.

Comment: There is no way to "get the real address", any more than there is a way to reach behind the fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe. The fundamental laws of physics govern our behavior. The fundamental laws of virtualization govern what happens in the VM, and unless you can figure out a bug in your virtualization software, and exploit it, you have no access to the actual underlying physical storage.

Comment: And as far as a "security mechanism" goes: any attempt to make bits uncopyable will have just as much of a chance of success as in making water not wet.

Comment: Big Fortune-500 companies spend millions of dollars to prevent this sort of things, and they generally fail. If someone wants to copy your product, or break the licensing scheme, they will do it no matter what you do. You can make it harder, but only for a while.